# Explode a .txt file into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Currently I have a file that looks something like this:

```
Awesomedude123 = 399,408 = September 16, 2012:
Username11 = 1,914,144 = September 16, 2012:
EpicSurfer = 1,031,427 = September 16, 2012:
```

What I want to do is transform it into a multidimensional array with PHP so it looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Awesomedude123
        [1] => 399,408
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Username11
        [1] => 1,914,144
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => EpicSurfer
        [1] => 1,031,427
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

)
```

I have tried using array_shift, but it didn't work out. Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated!

Comment: Post your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('File.txt'); // Get the file content
$data = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $data); // Clear newline characters

$data = explode(':', $data); // Get each record by : at end of line

unset($data[count($data) - 1]); // Clear the last empty element

$final_array = array();
foreach($data AS $row){ // Loop the exploded data
    $final_array[] = explode(' = ', $row); // Explode each row by Space=Space to each row of final_array
}

print_r($final_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to split your string:

```
myarray = array();
$file = fopen("myfile",'r');
while (!feof($file)) {
  $line = fgets($file);
  preg_match("/(\w+) = (.+) = (.+)/",$line,$matches);
  myarray[] = array($matches[1],$matches[2],$matches[3]);
}
```